# Mingw undefined reference to _mingw__winmain

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw

In a shared library I am trying to compile there is a prototype

`extern int main(int argc, char *argv[]);`

and an implementation of the `WinMain` function:

```
int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
    global_hinstance = hInstance;
    return main(__argc, __argv);
}
```

but when I try to compile it I get a few errors:

```
undefined reference to `__mingw_winmain_nShowCmd'
undefined reference to `__mingw_winmain_lpCmdLine'
undefined reference to `__mingw_winmain_hInstance'
```

Why do these pop up?

Comment: You want your shared library to have the `main()` or `WinMain()` function?  That's unusual.

Comment: take for example: SDL. It has it's own WinMain function so that it can remain portable between platforms and only ever need you to write a main() function.

Comment: Just a guess then: try passing the `-mwindows` option to set the PE header to subsystem GUI.